Adicionar as linhas de tendência à legenda do ggplot2
Eu gostaria de adicionar as linhas de tendência à legenda do gráfico. Abaico segue um modelo do código

year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006,
          2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006,
          2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006)

temp <- c(05, 08, 07, 05, 10, 13, 08, 
          10, 12, 11, 08, 14, 17, 10, 
          20, 18, 23, 25, 21, 28, 30)

type <- c("min","min","min","min","min","min","min",
          "mean","mean","mean","mean","mean","mean","mean",
          "max","max","max","max","max","max","max")

type <- as.factor(type)

series <- data.frame(year = year, temp = temp, type = type)


ggplot(series, aes(x = year, y = temp,  group = type)) + geom_line(aes(color = type)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = type)) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = type, color = type ), formula = 'y ~ x' , method=lm, se = F, linetype = "dashed", show.legend = T) + 
  scale_color_manual(values =  c("blue","black", "red") ) + 
  xlim(2000,2006) +
  labs(x = "Year", 
       y = "Temperatura",
       colour = "Legend")

Neste caso, mesmo sinalizando para mostrar a legenda no geom_smooth, ela não aparece na legenda final, que mostra apenas as legendas das séries temporais

No ggplot a função aes separa as "geom"'s por variáveis dos dados. Neste caso, se usar
aes(linetype = type)
em geom_smooth e depois der um nome diferente à legenda em labs tem duas legendas, uma para cada aes.
library(ggplot2)

year <- ggplot2year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006,
          2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006,
          2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006)

temp <- c(05, 08, 07, 05, 10, 13, 08, 
          10, 12, 11, 08, 14, 17, 10, 
          20, 18, 23, 25, 21, 28, 30)

type <- c("min","min","min","min","min","min","min",
          "mean","mean","mean","mean","mean","mean","mean",
          "max","max","max","max","max","max","max")

type <- as.factor(type)

series <- data.frame(year = year, temp = temp, type = type)


ggplot(series, aes(x = year, y = temp, color = type)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = type), formula = 'y ~ x' , method=lm, se = FALSE, show.legend = TRUE) + 
  scale_color_manual(values =  c("blue","black", "red")) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("dashed", "dashed", "dashed")) + 
  xlim(2000, 2006) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Temperatura",
       colour = "Legend",
       linetype = "Statistic")


Created on 2024-04-14 with reprex v2.1.0

Mas não creio que esta segunda legenda acrescente algo ao gráfico. O tipo de linha não separa as três linhas de regressão. Talvez baste um valor na segunda legenda.
No gráfico abaixo chamei à linha de regresão "avg. line" e atribui essa string (constante) a linetype, também na função aes. Depois, em scale_linetype_manual, usei um vetor com o attributo "names" ("avg. line") e o tipo de linha.
ggplot(series, aes(x = year, y = temp, color = type)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = "avg. line"), formula = 'y ~ x' , method=lm, se = FALSE, show.legend = TRUE) + 
  scale_color_manual(values =  c("blue","black", "red")) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(`avg. line` = "dashed")) + 
  xlim(2000, 2006) +
  labs(x = "Year", y = "Temperatura",
       colour = "Legend",
       linetype = "Statistic")


Created on 2024-04-14 with reprex v2.1.0
